# git and maven and releases and merges

Tags: git, maven

The Maven release plugin proceeds as follows:

1. change the version in the pom files.
2. commit
3. make a tag
4. change the version in the pom files again.
5. commit

(and then it checks out the tag and builds the release).

So, any merge from the branch on which this happens will pull the new, perhaps undesired, version #. Now, of course, cherry-pick exists, but manually identifying the commit list for all the upstream changes *except* the change for the versions is pretty annoying. Has anyone got an alternative? (other than to always release from a branch that no one is treating as 'upstream'?)

Comment: I'm confused, when would you ever want to do this?  You need to have 3 repository states: 1) before starting release, X.Y-SNAPSHOT; 2) in release condition, X.Y; 3) ready to start developing again, X.Y+1-SNAPSHOT.  I guess you want #2 to only exist in a branch, then #3 maybe isn't pushed out until the next "real" change?  You could always squash it with an interactive rebase, I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible when you are using GIT because a tag is only a pointer to a specific commit. So if you want to have the correct version number in your tagged POMs, you  have to modify and commit them first.
There is an option called `suppressCommitBeforeTag` in the maven-release-plugin which avoids commits of modified POMs. However, this does only work in SCMs like Subversion. If you enable this option in a GIT environment, your tagged POMs will contain the SNAPSHOT version from which you tried to make a release.

So making a release from a separate branch is the only option if you don't want to have intermediate POM modifications on your master branch.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *localCheckout* and *pushChanges* options of the release plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
        <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This way you do the whole release locally and do a final manual push in the end.